# If the blocks can only be traversed backwards, how do we know which one is the newest?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

Our blockchain consists of a range of blocks that are chained together with a linked list, going only backward, where each block header has a `prevHash` (bitcoin) or `parentHash` (ethereum).

Here's my question: If I can't go forward, how do I know I'm on the latest block?

Do I ask other peers in the network what block they are on?

And, theoretically, if I'm the only one on the network, what happens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If I can't go forward, how do I know I'm on the latest block?*

Each miner, after they created a block, broadcasts the new block (including its `number`) to the network.

So each node (both miners and non-miners) gets the latest block from this broadcasted message.

Plus, you can also ask other peers directly about their current block to validate if you're on the current block as well.

*Note: Sometimes multiple miners create and broadcast a valid block with the same `number`. Only one of them is accepted by the network (usually the one with the lowest `timestamp`) and the others are discarded as "uncle blocks".*

> *And, theoretically, if I'm the only one on the network, what happens then?*

Then you're the only miner as well, so you also have the last block number from the block that you mined.